# How can I get printing process on Mac in swift? Can I get notification when printing is complete?

Tags: macos, printing

I want to display the printing progress during the printing process of the printer, and pop up a prompt box after the printing is completed, but I don't know how to do it.

I tried NSPrinter in AppKit and PMPrinter in PrintCore, but can't find anyway.

Comment: Like part of total expected print time? Best of luck.

Comment: I just want to get the number of papers the printer has printed.